# textmate, how to mark text in a self-written bundle...?

Tags: bundle, textmate

i start to love textmate, but there is one feature i miss in textmate, which i always used in notepad++ or eclipse.

if you double click on a word in the text you get every word which is equally spelled like this. this feature makes code reading so easy, especially it is foreign code, so i thought to write a bundle for textmate on my own.

i am familiar with reg-ex and i think it is not a problem to use sed to find the usage of `$TM_CURRENT_WORD` in the document.

**my problem:**
i have never writen a textmate bundle and i don't know if there is a possibility to mark text out of a tm-bundle. i have not found an example code in a different bundle and i also don't know which "output" to use in the bundle editor, because no suggestion would fit to my problem.

any hint would help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to read the whole document, then do a find yourself for the (word the user selected), then output HTML (with the word selected in a CSS class or something)... which sounds like a fair bit of effort.

My pattern for this is:

Edit -> Find -> Use Selection for Find (Command + E)

then
  Edit -> Find -> Find Next
  Edit -> Find -> Find Next

So Command+E, Command+G, Command+G